# Web page-Sending an SMS on button click

Tags: html, web, button, sms, send

I was trying to make my app send an SMS automatically to the specified number when the user presses the button.

I can make it open the messenger and write the text but I can't make it send it automatically.

```
<html>  <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=sms://12341234?&body=Ok"></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible to achieve client-side for basic security reasons.

If a webpage was capable of triggering an SMS from the user's device without explicit confirmation then:

- It would leak the user's phone number to the controller of the webpage
- It could send SMS to premium rate numbers (including subscription services)

There are numerous services which can send an SMS using an API at the expense of the controller of the webpage. You can pay for one of those and trigger it with server side code when the page is loaded.